Incorrect parsing
Can somebody explain, why U256::from_str() in ethers.rs parses values incorrectly?
let amount_in = U256::from_str("1000000000").unwrap();
println!("Parsed Amount: {}", amount_in);
Parsed Amount: 68719476736
I'm working in ethers 2.0.14

When using U256::from_str() in ethers-rs, the function can mistakenly interpret the input string "1000000000" as a hexadecimal (base-16) value instead of a decimal (base-10) value.
To avoid this and ensure the string is treated as decimal, use U256::from_dec_str() instead. This explicitly tells the program to parse the input as a base-10 number.

True, 0x1000000000 == 68,719,476,736

Thank you very much!
